# Google Cloud dataflow : Read from a file with dynamic filename

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam

I am trying to build a pipeline on Google Cloud Dataflow that would do the following:

- Listen to events on Pubsub subscription
- Extract the filename from event text
- Read the file (from Google Cloud Storage bucket)
- Store the records in BigQuery

Following is the code:

```
Pipeline pipeline = //create pipeline
pipeline.apply("read events", PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription("sub"))
        .apply("Deserialise events", //Code that produces ParDo.SingleOutput<String, KV<String, byte[]>>)
        .apply(TextIO.read().from(""))???
```

I am struggling with 3rd step, not quite sure how to access the output of second step and use it in 3rd. I have tried writing the code that produces the following:

```
private ParDo.SingleOutput<KV<String, byte[]>, TextIO.Read> readFile(){
    //A class that extends DoFn<KV<String, byte[]>, TextIO.Read> and has TextIO.read wrapped into processElement method
}
```

However, I am not able to read the file content in subsequent step.

Could anyone please me know what do I need to write in 3rd and 4th steps so that I can consume the file line by line and store the output to BigQuery (or just log it).

Answer (score 4):

The natural way to express your read would be by using `TextIO.readAll()` method, which reads text files from an input `PCollection` of file names. This method has been introduced within the Beam codebase, but is not currently in a released version. It will be included in the Beam 2.2.0 release and the corresponding Dataflow 2.2.0 release.

Answer (score -1):

You can get this done with using SerializableFunction.

You can do

```
pipeline.apply(TextIO.read().from(new FileNameFn()));

public class FileNameFn implements SerializableFunction<inputFileNameString, outputQualifiedFileNameStringWithBucket>
```

Obvious you can  pass bucket name and other parameter statically while creating this class instance by constructor arguments.

Hope this will help.

Comment: The method you're referring to does not exist: TextIO.read().from() is applicable only either to String or to ValueProvider<String>. You might have confused it with the more dynamic methods in write().