# Google Dataflow: how to parse big file with valid JSON array from FileIO.ReadableFile

Tags: java, json, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

In my pipeline `FileIO.readMatches()` transform reads big JSON file(around 300-400MB) with a valid JSON array and returns `FileIO.ReadableFile` object to the next transform. My task is to read each JSON object from that JSON array, add new properties and output to the next transform.

At the moment my code to parse the JSON file looks like this:

```java
        // file is a FileIO.ReadableFile object 
        InputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.readFullyAsBytes());
        // Im using gson library to parse JSON
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(bis, "UTF-8"));
        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
        reader.beginArray();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            JsonObject jsonObject = jsonParser.parse(reader).getAsJsonObject();
            jsonObject.addProperty("Somename", "Somedata");
            // processContext is a ProcessContext object
            processContext.output(jsonObject.toString());
        }
        reader.close();
```

In this case the whole content of the file will be in my memory which brings options to get  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Im searching for solution to read one by one all JSON objects without keeping the whole file in my memory.
Possible solution is to use method `open()` from object `FileIO.ReadableFile` which returns `ReadableByteChannel` channel but Im not sure how to use that channel to read specifically one JSON object from that channel.

**Updated solution**
This is my updated solution which reads the file line by line

```java
    ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {
        // file is a FileIO.ReadableFile 
        readableByteChannel = file.open();
        inputStream = Channels.newInputStream(readableByteChannel);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.length() > 1) {
                // my final output should contain both filename and line
                processContext.output(fileName + file);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        logger.error("Exception during reading the file: {}", ex);
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(bufferedReader);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
    }
```

I see that this solution doesnt work with Dataflow running on n1-standard-1 machine and throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` exception and works correctly on n1-standard-2 machine.

Comment: Is the entire JSON file meant to be parsed in a single transform step? You can use the `TextIO` class to read the JSON file and parse each JSON array individually instead of having to hold the entire file in memory. Can you provide more context on how your pipeline is defined in your code example?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use TextIO in my solution, because I need the file name and file content in the same transform step. I asked question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48463607/google-dataflow-attaching-filename-to-the-message). In my current post I didn't mention that part to simplify my question. My idea is to get FileIO.ReadableFile as input for my transform step, extract file name and file content from that input object, parse each line from file and output that file with additional information from file name to the next transform step.

Answer (score 0):

`ReadableByteChannel` is a java NIO API, introduced in Java 7. Java [provides a way](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html#newInputStream(java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel)) to convert it to an InputStream: `InputStream bis = Channels.newInputStream(file.open());` - I believe this is the only change you need to make.

Comment: Hi jkff, thanks for your response. Actually, I already did it like you said: I read my input stream line by line and output to the next transform. I'm running my application on the n1-standard-1 machine which has around 500 MB heap memory. But it looks like its not enough because I see `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` exception from the line `processContext.output(message)`. I expected that lowest n1-standard-1 machine should be enough for such transformation. What is your opinion? Is it my code or machine is too low?

Comment: Your code, as posted, uses new ByteArrayInputStream(file.readFullyAsBytes()) which reads the entire file in memory. Could you post your updated code?